# Gtx 750ti render time

Tags: rendering

I am from India and learning blender from few weeks.

When I render demo file bmw27 it takes 22 minutes with CPU and 11 minutes with GPU (gtx 750ti). Default settings.

I see some video on YouTube same GPU and same file within 2 minutes.

I want to know that this time is ok or there is problem.

My pc is 
I5 3330
H77m-d3h (gigabyte)
8gb ddr3 ram
Gtx MSI 750ti 2 GB ddr5 
Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: do you know if you used the same number of samples as was used in the video? The number of samples was changed in that demo file at some point, if the video was made before they increased it then no wonder it takes you longer to render.

Comment: You can find a Blender integrated benchmarking system right here:
https://opendata.blender.org/

Comment: Thank you David and morph3us. The problem was that i had select square sample option. I don't know what is this, can you tell me that what is this.